# JavaScript Increment ++ Opacity On each Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, opacity, increment

Hi i am having trouble incrementing the `opacity` of a `background-color:hsla() div` using JavaScript. This is the code i am using...

```
$( "#Opacity" ).button().click(function() {
var x = 0.1;
var Opacity = ++x;
$( "#TimeDate, #Weather, #ticker, #Pages" ).css( "background-color", "hsla(0,0%,0%,"+Opacity +")" );
        Cookie.set('bgo', $('#TimeDate, #Weather, #ticker, #Pages').css('background-color'), 365);
        return false;
});
```

The end result I would like is for the opacity to start off at the previous setting and then for it to increase by 0.1 every time the button is clicked until it reaches 1 then for it to return to 0 and then start increasing by 0.1 on each click again and so forth.

Thanks in advance,
Chris

Comment: `++` works with integers, so use whole numbers and divide by ten, and declare the inital value outside the function.

Comment: Thanks for the answer it also worked your way but the one bellow works great for what i want :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using this code opacity is always 1.1

Correct the function to the below:

```
Opacity = 0.1

$( "#Opacity" ).button().click(function() {

    Opacity = (Opacity==1) ? 0 : (Opacity + 0.1);
    $( "#TimeDate, #Weather, #ticker, #Pages" ).css( "background-color", "hsla(0,0   %,0%,"+Opacity +")" );
    Cookie.set('bgo', $('#TimeDate, #Weather, #ticker, #Pages').css('background-color'), 365);
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much but how do i now make it go back to 0 once it reaches 1?

Comment: It's already done in the line `Opacity = (Opacity==1) ? 0 : (Opacity + 0.1);`. That's a short form of `if (Opacity==1) Opacity=0 else Opacity=Opacity+0.1`

Comment: ahh right but it doesn't seem to be working for me :/ it doesn't go back to 0 it just keeps increasing by 0.1 on every click. i made it output the value so i could see what it was doing. On page refresh the button resets to 0 again but i would like it to start where it left off:/ EDIT: it looks like it never actually gets to 1 ? it goes to 0.99* and 3=3.04 8=0.79* 9=0.89*   where * means recurring

Comment: i change it to `Opacity = (Opacity > 1) ? 0 : (Opacity + 0.1);` but i would still like to know how to make sure it rounds to 1 significant figure

Comment: Maybe use toFixed(1): `Opacity = (Math.Round(Opacity)==1) ? 0 : (Opacity + 0.1); Opacity = Opacity.toFixed(1);`